# Trying to add a library to project in "C" with "gcc -L" on Linux - error

Tags: c

Hi im trying to add a library to my C project for a class task but I cant get it to work.

When I use `gcc -L ../build/lib ./bigint/src -lbigint` it shows the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./bigint/src/ can not be found: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: -lbigint can not be found
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my directories do look like this:

```
root <- here im in the terminal trying, using the command
- bigint
-- src
--- bigint.c
--- bigint.h
--- bigint.h.gch
--- bigint.o
--- libbigint.a
--- support.h
--- support.g.gch
-- tst
- project.c
- project.h
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a seperate `-L` for each lib directory. Assuming you really do want `./bigint/src` to be a lib directory:

```
gcc -L ../build/lib -L ./bigint/src <C file or object file> -lbigint
```

Comment: I want to add the library `libbigint.a` to the main lib directory if i got the instructions right

Comment: @xDrago Did you try the above solution? It should work but if not then please provide info on what happens after the change.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the result I want to have and i am basicly just following instructions from the task which gives me the exact command I already tried. However if I try your command I get the following error: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In Function »_start«:
(.text+0x20): Warning: undefined Reference on »main«
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: Oh, you didn't give the C file to compile or object file to link. Should be something like: `gcc -L ../build/lib -L ./bigint/src -lbigint project.c`. Assuming all the code is in `project.c`. Unfortunately that's getting a bit beyond the scope of this question. Suggest you start a seperate question for that.

Comment: It worked with your help now. I thought it will do something else than it actually does. So it compiles my project in adds the library to it?

Comment: On the command line, put libraries (`-lxyz` options) after source files and object files — there are systems where that is crucial, and others where it is optional.  (The `-L` options can go anywhere before the `-l` options.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. Corrected now. Thanks for pointing that out.